# How thick should be the sponge for a swiss roll?

Tags: swiss-roll, thickness

How thick should be the sponge for a swiss roll to roll easily without breaking and hold its shape?

I saw some pictures that look perfect and then some where the sponge looks too thick.

How do I figure out the perfect thickness of the sponge?

Comment: What sponge recipe are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally when ever I do Swiss rolls or anything requiring me to roll or manipulate the sponge in any way I'll use a Genoise sponge recipe. It's a bit more effort to make than a bog standard pound cake recipe but worth it.

While still warm I've managed to roll it anywhere between 2mm thick and 3cm with little or no cracks or splits.

In my opinion the optimum thickness for a full sized Swiss roll is around 1cm thick, but obviously if making canape sized versions you'll be looking more towards the 2mm thickness.

Comment: I was thinking of using Victoria sponge which is what I find in many swiss roll recipes

Comment: @Doug: Yes I did but it took a few tries. Didn't get exact 1 cm but close to it :)